# how do I get a document from elasticsearch only by id from all the index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have a project in python where i need to get a document from one of for **indexes index_1 2 3 or 4** but i only have the id and in the near future i will have 4 more idexe so **8** in total i can't afford to look for the doc in every one of the 8.

so my question is, is there a way to get the doc directly by the id? if not is there an alternative? thank you very much

here is what i have until now:

```
url = settings.ES_URL+"/{}/_doc/{}?pretty=false"
url = url.format(index, id)
r = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('*****', '*******'))
```

and i try every index but that's not what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Index Alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-add-alias.html). Essentially it still searches in multiple indexes, but you don't have to mention individual index names while searching.

Say I have the below two indexes

```
PUT my_index_001    

PUT my_index_002
```

And below two documents in those indexes

```
POST my_index_001/_doc/1234
{
  "myfield": "test"
}

POST my_index_002/_doc/1235
{
  "myfield": "test"
}
```

I can create my alias index `my_index` in the below fashion

```
PUT /my_index_001/_alias/my_index

PUT /my_index_002/_alias/my_index
```

Now you can simply use this index to search the document via any `term` or `match` query.

```
POST my_index/_search.          <--- Note the index used here to search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": "1234"             <--- Note the field `_id`
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you cannot get the document directly like this `GET my_index/_doc/1234` using the concept of Alias as firstly that is a single index operation and I believe the whole purpose of having alias is to enhance search functionality seamlessly and not meant for direct document retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias feature of elasticsearch to map all indices under one alias. Later in place of querying all 8 indices, query associated alias index and that will do the job for you to search through all 8 and return the results.